# Set Images Randomly for buttons from array and take button's cgrect's from array

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

I have 42 buttons in my storyboard and I have take array of images. In this array there are total 7 images.

```
NSArray *arrimg=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"book.png", @"lock.png", @"Exclamation.png", @"game.png", @"Music.png", @"Videos.png", @"Camera32.png", nil];
```

So how could I take random images every time on button?

Should I take button collection or do anything else?

Note:- I have not take buttons programatically.

a new question stand: how to take all 42 button's CGRect from array and display randomly in screen.

```
NSMutableArray *mutarr=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
NSMutableArray *array=[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:mutarr];
[array addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGRect:CGRectMake(50, 50, 47, 25)]];
[array addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGRect:CGRectMake(97, 50, 47, 25)]];
[array addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGRect:CGRectMake(144, 50, 47, 25)]];
CGRect someRect1 = [[array objectAtIndex:0] CGRectValue];
CGRect someRect2 = [[array objectAtIndex:0] CGRectValue];
CGRect someRect3 = [[array objectAtIndex:0] CGRectValue];
```

I don't know what to do ahead.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have tried this and it works...

in viewdidload:

```
arrimg=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"book.png",@"lock.png",@"Exclamation.png",@"game.png",@"Music.png",@"Videos.png",@"Camera32.png", nil];


NSMutableArray *mutArrayb = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:arrimg];
NSUInteger count = [mutArrayb count];
if (count > 1)
{
    for (NSUInteger i = count - 1; i > 0; --i) {
        [mutArrayb exchangeObjectAtIndex:i withObjectAtIndex:arc4random_uniform((int32_t)(i + 1))];
        NSLog(@"%@",[mutArrayb objectAtIndex:i]);
    }
}
//rndmim=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:7];
rndmim = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:mutArrayb];
for (int i=0; i<7; i++)
{
    NSLog(@"%d  %@",i,[rndmim objectAtIndex:i]);
    [btn1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[rndmim objectAtIndex:0]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btn2 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[rndmim objectAtIndex:1]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btn3 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[rndmim objectAtIndex:2]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btn4 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[rndmim objectAtIndex:0]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btn5 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[rndmim objectAtIndex:4]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btn6 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[rndmim objectAtIndex:5]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btn7 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[rndmim objectAtIndex:6]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btn8 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[rndmim objectAtIndex:1]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btn9 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[rndmim objectAtIndex:5]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btn10 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[rndmim objectAtIndex:0]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btn11 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[rndmim objectAtIndex:5]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btn12 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[rndmim objectAtIndex:3]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btn13 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[rndmim objectAtIndex:3]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btn14 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[rndmim objectAtIndex:1]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btn15 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[rndmim objectAtIndex:5]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btn16 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[rndmim objectAtIndex:2]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btn17 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[rndmim objectAtIndex:3]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btn18 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[rndmim objectAtIndex:1]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btn19 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[rndmim objectAtIndex:0]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btn20 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[rndmim objectAtIndex:0]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btn21 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[rndmim objectAtIndex:2]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btn22 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[rndmim objectAtIndex:3]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btn23 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[rndmim objectAtIndex:4]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btn24 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[rndmim objectAtIndex:5]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btn25 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[rndmim objectAtIndex:6]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btn26 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[rndmim objectAtIndex:4]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btn27 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[rndmim objectAtIndex:5]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btn28 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[rndmim objectAtIndex:0]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btn29 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[rndmim objectAtIndex:1]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btn30 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[rndmim objectAtIndex:6]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btn31 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[rndmim objectAtIndex:3]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btn32 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[rndmim objectAtIndex:0]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btn33 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[rndmim objectAtIndex:5]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btn34 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[rndmim objectAtIndex:6]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btn35 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[rndmim objectAtIndex:3]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btn36 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[rndmim objectAtIndex:5]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btn37 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[rndmim objectAtIndex:0]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btn38 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[rndmim objectAtIndex:1]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btn39 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[rndmim objectAtIndex:2]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btn40 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[rndmim objectAtIndex:3]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btn41 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[rndmim objectAtIndex:5]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btn42 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[rndmim objectAtIndex:5]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

when i go back to previous view and come back again in this view images change again...it works well....

Answer (score 1):

Give tag to each 42 button from 0 to 41

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        arrimg=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"book.png", @"lock.png", @"Exclamation.png", @"game.png", @"Music.png", @"Videos.png", @"Camera32.png", nil];
        NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:1.0f target:self selector:@selector(performAction) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
        [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:timer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
    }
    -(void)performAction {

    NSInteger randomNumberForImage = rand() % (arrimg.count);
    NSInteger randomNumberForButton=rand()%(numberOfButton);// numberOfButton=42;
    UIButton *btn=[self viewWithTag:randomNumberForButton];
    [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[arrimg objectAtIndex:randomNumberForImage]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

}
```

Comment: hey @Yagnesh he was saying he use 42 buttons and your code is for 1 button plz edit your question.:)

Comment: vote + 1 for answer i have same answer code so dont put it here BTW nice coding@Yagnesh

Comment: @yagnesh what is view with tag

Comment: button have property namely "tag" u can define tag number for each button to uniquely identify.  Using that tag name access button programmatically using viewWithTag

Answer (score 0):

TRY THIS...

```
int length = [myArray count];
// Get random value between 0 and 99 if your count is 100
int randomindex = arc4random() % length;

Object randomObj = [myArray objectAtIndex:randomindex];
```

add the above code in a function and call this from your viewWillAppear.